# What is the general mechanism behind perfusion PET imaging

Tags: imaging

I understand how tracer kinetics can be used to determine binding potential but how it can be used to detect perfusion eludes me.

Comment: How PET works is more of a physics question? Can you clarify what exactly you are asking?

Comment: Alex - do you literally mean "perfusion" - like blood perfusion imaging - - - OR - - - do you mean like PET with 18O-fluorodeoxyglucose uptake imaging?